# Does Omniauth require SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I was wondering if OmniAuth requires a SSL license to login with both Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: SSL is a protocol, there is no such thing as an "SSL license".

Comment: What's the point of purchasing a license then?

Comment: Who told you that you need to purchase a license?

Comment: Verisign? Digicert? They sell SSL certs...

Comment: My grandma sells apples, too, will you also want an "SSL License" from her? :-) Pay attention to the details, they sell *certificates*. Certificates are an (optional, questionable) component of authenticating a server. Since you are not running a server, but rather a *client* by the sound of it, you will not even need a certificate. I do recommend you learn the basics of public key infrastructure, though, so you can make sure your own application is secure and not prone to being phished during your next coffee+wifi at Starbucks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need (to buy) a *[certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Server_setup)*, if that's what you mean by SSL license.